# PyConcorde gives clearly non-optimal solutions

Tags: python

I am trying to use PyConcorde on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Python 3.10.12. First I was trying to solve an asymmetric problem but the solution was an obvious non-optimal.
[image: real time matrix]

Then I symmetrized the distance matrix and solve it but it is also far from optimal, also having a bird-flight distance did not work.
[image: bird flight time matrix]

I am creating my own TSPLIB file and it is as follows. It is .tsp in the local but I cannot upload .tsp files here hence I changed the extension of it. I can provide the file if requested. Also, the code I am running is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from concorde.tsp import TSPSolver
from concorde.tests.data_utils import get_dataset_path

def generate_tsp_file(file_name, directory):
data_from_csv = pd.read_csv(file_name + '.csv')
distance_matrix = data_from_csv.values
file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
n = len(distance_matrix)
f.write("NAME: temp\n")
f.write(f"TYPE: TSP\n")
f.write(f"DIMENSION: {n}\n")
f.write("EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EXPLICIT\n")
f.write("EDGE_WEIGHT_FORMAT: FULL_MATRIX\n")
f.write("EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION\n")
np.savetxt(f, distance_matrix, fmt='%d')
return file_path

def solve_tsp(file_path):
fname = get_dataset_path(file_path)
solver = TSPSolver.from_tspfile(fname)
solution = solver.solve()
return solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
directory_path = '/pyconcorde/pyconcorde/concorde/tests/data'
file_name = 'distance_matrix'
tsp_file = generate_tsp_file(file_name, directory_path)
solution = solve_tsp(tsp_file)
print(solution.optimal_value)
print(solution.tour)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? If not, I can look at it if you could provide the CSV file you're using to create the `.tsp` file. It'll be easier to reproduce your problem.